# Removing heavy files from a repository

Tags: git, gitlab, commit

I have accidentally commit and pushed a heavy folder with picture. I need to relieve the repository but I can't totally delete the pictures because of the history. I tried git revert or filter branch but nothing worked, the .git is still heavy

Comment: No because I made other commit and push after

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history